# Equivalence relation for the union of 2 sets

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

If R1 and R2 are 2 equivalence relations on set S, then Prove that R1 U R2 is reflexive, symmetric but needn't be transitive.

This is the question and I understand why it needn't be transitive but the problem is how do I write it on a paper so that the questioner or examiner can understand that I understand ?

Comment: Show a simple example.  You just need one.

Comment: How do I express it generally on the paper?

Comment: Using some arbitary variable a that belongs to R1......, something like that

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\{x,y,z\}$. Besides the reflexive relations $k=k$ for $k\in S$, $R_1$ also has the equivalence $x=y$ while $R_2$ also has the equivalence $y=z$. Then in $R_1\cup R_2$, $x=y$ and $y=z$ but $x\ne z$.

The union of two equivalence relations over the same set is always reflexive and symmetric: any relation $a=a$ or $a=b$ in the union must come from at least one of the component equivalences, and for $a=b$ there will always be a $b=a$ in the same equivalence $a=b$ was found in.